# Which functional language(s) does Clojure share the most in common with?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

I don't know much about functional programming but am interested in learning Clojure.

Are there any functional languages that would be a good point of reference to understand how functional programming works in Clojure?

Or is Clojure different enough in its functional programming approach that I would be better off to just focus on Clojure's functional features by themselves?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clojure is a **lisp** so learning other lisps will help a lot in getting used to the parts of the "lisp culture" or general way of doing things. Remember that Clojure breaks significantly with Common Lisp though.

Clojure is **lazy** so learning Haskell will really help get you used to the idea of real lazy programming.

Clojure is **concurrent** so learning a little bit of Erlang will help though you will need to keep in mind that Erlang includes a lot about distributed programming while clojure is all about concurrent programming that is not necessarily distributed.

Comment: Protocols are also somewhat similar to type classes in Haskell

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp of course :) Scheme might be an easier introduction though and easier to get a stable, simple, common environment.

Comment: I don't know about "of course". Scheme has a stronger "cultural emphasis" on immutable functional programming, whereas a lot of common lisp code is bristling with `setf`s.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure and Lisp share a lot of ideas with Ruby as well, though the syntax is much different